# How to put tab on top in windows mobile 6.5

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-mobile-6

I m creating a windows mobile application. In the application i have a tab control , by default the position of tab page menu is comming at buttom but i wanted it on top.

Is there any way to do it.

Any help appreciated
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

if you're using the standing System.Windows.Forms.TabControl then you cannot. The customizability of that control is extremely limited.

You have two options:

1. roll your own tab control.
2. look at other third party libraries. One very popular (and high quality) control suite for windows mobile is the [Rescoe Mobile Forms Toolkit](http://www.resco.net/developer/mobileformstoolkit/). It has a tab control that is very customizable.